# Delete elements finishing by some characters from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, delete-row

I'm working on python scripts and I have many problems.

I would like to know if it is possible to delete elements from a list, but only ones finishing by certain characters.

For instance, I have the list :
`list1 = [SOFA_CONFORT, SOFA, CHAIR_CONFORT, CHAIR]`

and I would like to get the list:
`list2 = [SOFA, CHAIR]` by deleting the elements ending with "_CONFORT".

I'm not supposed to know the elements of the list, I want the script to do it all by itself.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is this a list of strings?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Have you tried anything?

Comment: The list is a list of string yes.

Comment: I tried to use the "remove()" function but i can't get it working for my application.

Answer (score 8):

That's a standard case of list comprehension with an `if` statement:

```
list1 = ["SOFA_CONFORT", "SOFA", "CHAIR_CONFORT", "CHAIR"]
list2 = [val for val in list1 if not val.endswith("_CONFORT")]
print(list2) # prints ['SOFA', 'CHAIR']
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

And if i want to keep some elements of a list how can i do that ?

For instance, i have the list :
`list3 = [LivingRoom_Sofa_Confort, BedRoom_Sofa_Confort, Kitchen_Chair_COnfort...]`

And i would like to keep only the elements that contain "Sofa". To get the list :
`list4 = [LivingRoom_Sofa_Confort, BedRoom_Sofa_Confort...]`

Comment: `list4 = [val for val in list3 if "Sofa" in val]`

Answer (score 6):

Could also use `filter`:

```
list2 = filter(lambda x: not x.endswith('_CONFORT'), list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it, among of them using buitl-in method `filter`:

```
>>> list1 = ['SOFA_CONFORT', 'SOFA', 'CHAIR_CONFORT', 'CHAIR']
>>> list2 = filter(lambda s: not s.endswith('_CONFORT'), list1)
['SOFA', 'CHAIR']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of what list comprehensions are for!
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

For example, if you have the list

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

then the following list comprehension returns a list of only those elements in this list that are larger than three:

```
my_short_list = [element for element in my_list if element > 3]
```

If you combine this with the `endswith()` method that strings have (e.g. `"CHAIR_CONFORT".endswith("CONFORT")` thwn I'm sure you can figure out how to get what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use regular expressions, something along the lines of

```
import re
list1 = ["SOFA_CONFORT", "SOFA", "CHAIR_CONFORT", "CHAIR"]
list1=[string for string in list1 if not re.search('_CONFORT$', string)]
```

See here for more details : 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: No need to use regex for such a simple task.
OP will also get a wrong output, `['SOFA', 'SOFA', 'CHAIR', 'CHAIR]`

Comment: You're right, I read the question wrong, I edited my answer. Regexes might be a bit overkill but that doesn't seem to be that bad to use them here.